# unit testing in spring boot giving error when exception thrown in service

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

So, I have this unit test that I need to run.

```
@MockBean
private AppServiceImpl appService;


@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenAppIdIsNull() throws Exception {
    File inputFile = this.getJsonFile();
    RequestDto requestDto = objectMapper.readValue(inputFile.getAbsoluteFile(),
            RequestDto.class);
    AppData appData = requestDto.getAppData();
    appData.setAppId(null);
    requestDto.setAppData(appData);
    when(appService.getUrl(requestDto, "header")).thenThrow(new RequestNotValidException());
    String payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestDto);
    this.mockMvc.perform(post(Base_URL + "app/requesturl")
            .contentType(contentType).content(payload).header(this.Header, "header"))
            .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
}
```

Interface for service:

SO when I run this test, it throws an exception and doesn't actually assert the test here.

I have added `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)` on top of `RequestNotValidException` and it extends `RunTimeException`

And in the second test case, I get empty response. I tried this API vis Postman and I get the response. Everything works fine there.

```
@Test
public void getCardRegistration() throws Exception {
    File inputFile = this.getJsonFile();
    RequestDto requestDto = objectMapper.readValue(inputFile.getAbsoluteFile(), RequestDto.class);
    ResponseDto responseDto = new ResponseDto();
    responseDto.setURL(AuthUtils.randomStringToken(35));
    given(appService.getRegistrationUrl(requestDto, "header")).willReturn(responseDto);
    String payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestDto);
    MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(post(Base_URL + "app/requesturl")
            .contentType(contentType).content(payload).header(this.Header, "header"))
            .andReturn();
    String contentAsString = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
}
```

Controller content:

```
    @Autowired
    IAppService appService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/app/requesturl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseDto getCardsRegistration(@RequestBody @Valid RequestDto requestDto, @RequestHeader(value="X-App-Name", required = true) String header) throws RequestNotValidException, JsonProcessingException {
    log.info("Request received in controller: "+ mapper.writeValueAsString(cardRegistrationRequestDto));
    log.info("Header value: "+ header);

    return this.appService.getRegistrationUrl(requestDto, header);
}
```

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AppRestControllerTest {

    protected String Base_URL = "/app";

    protected String Header = "X-App-Name";

    protected MediaType contentType = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(),
            Charset.forName("utf8"));

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @MockBean
    private AppServiceImpl appService;

    @Mock
    private AppRegistrationRepository appRegistrationRepository;


        @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MapperFacade mapperFacade = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build().getMapperFacade();
        appService = new AppServiceImpl(appRegistrationRepository, mapperFacade);
    }
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Did you tried '@Test(expected = RequestNotValidException.class) ' in 1st case?

Comment: Also, you can look for this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336277/how-to-check-string-in-response-body-with-mockmvc), looks that it can help you with your tests. (look for ".andExpect" method

Comment: Ah yes. It works. It didn't occur to me before. 
What am I missing in the second test case?

Comment: Can I see your full configuration? Update post, please

Comment: Which configurations?

Comment: Test config (full test class). And also it would be nice to see your controller.

Comment: Okay. 
There's nothing more in the test class except these two methods. 
I'll add the controller.

Comment: All annotations are important. The way how you configure controller in test are also important

Comment: @PospolitaNikita Updated

Comment: Do you have @RestController above your controller class?

Comment: Yes, I have @RestController above the controller class

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)
public class AppRestControllerTest {
```

Or

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AppRestControllerTest {
```

In your tests

Comment: with the first block, all the test cases failed. 
and nothing changed when I added the second block.

Comment: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: Failed to load because of what?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: Will the content always be empty for RestController ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext - it's still is not the cause of exception. (: Can you give full stack trace?

"Will the content always be empty for RestController ?" - No, it's a configuration problem, and there are already another answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691094/spring-boot-integration-test-responding-with-empty-body-mockmvc

Comment: maybe it's because you didn't call "initMocks(this);" on @Before init method

Comment: It worked when I just do andExpect(status().isOk()). 
It fails when I try to access the content.