# ResponseBody is printing empty body for spring boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691094/spring-boot-integration-test-responding-with-empty-body-mockmvc) to run my spring-boot controller test. but however, my code is still printing an empty body. I tried calling the real method and mocked one, is it something IntelliJ issue or am I missing something?

below is the test code.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AnimalController.class)
class AnimalControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;
    @MockBean
    AnimalService animalService;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        AnimalDto response = new AnimalDto();
        response.setId(1l);
       when(animalService.add(any())).thenReturn(response);
    }

    @Test
    void addAnimal() throws Exception {
        AnimalDto animalDto = new AnimalDto();
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                   .post("/animal/add")
                   .content(asJsonString(new AnimalDto(null, "dog", null,null, null, null, null)))
                   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                   .andExpect(status().isOk())
                   .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                   .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id").exists());

    }
}
```

below is my actual controller

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@RequestMapping("/animal")
public class AnimalController {

    AnimalService animalService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public AnimalDto addAnimal(@Valid @RequestBody AnimalDto animalDto){
        return animalService.add(animalDto);
    }
}
```

and my service class:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Slf4j
public class AnimalService {

    AnimalRepository animalRepository;
    SourceToDestinationMapper mapper;

    public AnimalDto add(AnimalDto animalDto) {
        Animal animal = mapper.animalDtoToAnimal(animalDto);
        Animal savedAnimal = animalRepository.save(animal);
        log.debug("animal object saved:",animal);
        return mapper.animalToAnimalDto(savedAnimal);
    }
}
```

this is how my output looks like

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /animal/add
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json", Content-Length:"103"]
             Body = {"id":null,"title":"dog","located":null,"type":null,"preference":null,"favoriteRooms":null,"room":null}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.self.zoo.controller.AnimalController
           Method = com.self.zoo.controller.AnimalController#addAnimal(AnimalDto)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.id"

    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:304)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertExistsAndReturn(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:328)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.exists(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:192)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$exists$3(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
    at com.self.zoo.controller.AnimalControllerTest.addAnimal(AnimalControllerTest.java:54)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
```

Comment: As a general note, your service usually should be responsible for returning a DTO: The essence of the controller's job is to be an adapter between "HTTP" on one side and "internal data model" on the other. In long-lived applications, you might end up with several different DTOs for the same database model.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-sorry I am not following you. Did I miss some best practices here?

Comment: Yes; the service should return `Animal`, and the controller is responsible for the `Animal<->AnimalDto` lifecycle. (Note that this does not explain exactly what your bug is, but it might make debugging it easier.)

Comment: Any luck yet? I'm facing the same problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing *@BeforeAll* anotation as in Junit5 we need that one

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your mapper works correctly:

- try without mapper do convert by your own dto->Model and vice versa?
- try invalidate cache restart IntelliJ
- use postman to test API

Comment: first 2 I already tried and they are working

Comment: Even postman API